How do I ask about ethnicity in a survey questions?
For a statistics course I am in we have to do a survey and must include questions regarding ethnicity.
How do I go about asking people for their ethnicity? What options should be present?
My current question is:


Which of the following best describes your ethnicity?

White
Hispanic/Latino
East Asian
South Asian
Pacific Islander
Hawaiian
Other (please specify): _______
I prefer not to say




But this go me thinking, should I draw more specifications? Is West Asian an ethnicity I should list?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.
I would love to hear how you have addressed asking about race.

By the looks of it you are based in the US; the questions they ask there on a regular basis are very different than for instance in Europe or Australia. fwiw, from a European perspective, the US 'ethnicity' questions are very frank, and if you ask me personally, I find them blunt and racist. So a little geographic context could help, as well as the type of questionnaire and some scientific details (research questions etc) can aid in answering this question.

Like AliceD, I'm assuming you're in the US. Most people use the US Census categories unless they have an explicit reason and argument for using a different scheme for their particular case.
